# Getting access to LinkedIn API r_organization_social

Tags: linkedin-api

how can I get access to the r_organization_social of the LinkedIn API to retrieve data about different companies?

Thanks in advance!

I created my app in the developer portal and have access to:
w_member_social
r_liteprofile
r_emailaddress

But I am not sure how to get the r_organization_social scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to apply for [marketing developer platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access#marketing).

Open your app, then go to the product and request access to Marketing Developer Platform.[image]

Once you click request to access, then you have to accept their policy, then there will be a link to request access and then you have to fill up the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Platform Access Form. Once they approved this, you will have the w_organization_social, r_organization_social, and [much more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access#marketing).
[image]

For more information, please visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access#marketing).

Comment: Looks like they removed that product, logged in with a premium account.

Comment: Hi, can you please share more information what actually you want to say.

Comment: the product Marketing Developer Platform is no longer available, the closest think I could find is Community Management API (I'm a premium user)